# Can any one explain the reasons of Validity and Invalidity of the below code

Tags: c#, oop

Can any one explain the reasons of Validity and Invalidity of following C# code:

```
class A 
{
    protected void ProtectedFunction() 
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.ProtectedFunction(); //Valid (Point 2)
    }
}

class B : A 
{
    public void Function_B() 
    {
        A a = new A();            
        base.ProtectedFunction();//Valid (Point 1)
        a.ProtectedFunction(); //Invalid, why??? (Point 1)

        B b = new B();
        b.ProtectedFunction(); //Valid, called by instance b (Point 2)

        ProtectedFunction(); //Valid, called by base instance
    }
}

class C : B 
{
    public void Function_C() 
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.ProtectedFunction(); //Invalid, why??? (Point 1)

        B b = new B();
        b.ProtectedFunction(); //Invalid, why??? (Point 2)

        C c = new C();
        c.ProtectedFunction(); //Valid, called by instance c (Point 2)

        ProtectedFunction(); //Valid, called by base instance
    }
}
```

It seems like the instance in its own class/context can access the protected method but the same instance out of class/context cannot access the method.

The question is when accessing by instance, the code being executed is not in the instance own context but in another instance's context (though of same class).

Comment: this is how protected keyword works

Answer (score 0):

All Point 1s are invalid since a protected method can be called from the class where they are defined; or from child classes in case of inheritance; a protected method can not be called on instances.

But there is one exception, whenever an instance of a class is used inside the class definition, protected methods can be accessed; so Point 2s are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Private = only this class can use.

Protected = only this class and derived classes can use.

with `a = new A()` you are creating an instance of a and accessing as an outsider so this method is not available.

If you want to access a member through an instance, it should be public (or internal if you only want to access from within the assembly)

Answer (score 0):

These calls

```
A a = new A();            
a.ProtectedFunction(); //Invalid, why??? (Point 1)
```

are all invalid because ProtectedFunction() is not accessible from outside the *instance* of a class. So even though you are calling it from an inherited class, you are calling a difference instance (or, object, if you like) so you can no longer access it.

A real world example to get your head around this might be emails.  I can read my own private emails, but you can't read mine.  If I have children they inherit from me the ability to read their own private emails - but they still can't read mine!